# Unity3D Camera constantly moving

Tags: c#, unity, camera

I'm trying to make my own first person camera controls in unity that use both thumbsticks on a joypad. I have this working fine. However, when I move the right thumb stick (the one uses to look left / right & up / down the camera begins to constantly update.

Here is my joypad movement code:

```
   // Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    float speed = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("LeftRight") * sensitivityX;

    rotationY += Input.GetAxis("UpDown") * sensitivityY;
    rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, speed, 0);

}
```

To control the left thumb stick, I've simply attached the my script to a first person character controller Unity provide.

I know my code is updating every frame, but I assumed that it would only update as and when I press the right thumb stick. If that isn't the case, is there a way I can limit it to only increment when I move the right thumb stick?

Comment: Did you try using Debug.Log to show what the GetAxis call is saying? And check the dead zone values on the input manager? Didn't I suggest this before in a very similar post a few days ago (which has now strangely disappeared)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine, so I assume the problem is somewhere else. The one I can think of: these axes have very small "Gravity" value in Input Manager (i.e. "Speed in units per second that the axis falls toward neutral when no buttons are pressed", from [this page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Input.html) in Unity Manual).